Using NGXS state data in a forkjoin
Within an Angular component I have to retrieve data from an API then use it with some state data from an NGXS state variable.  In my component I have this:
  @Select(MyObjectState.get)
  public readonly myobjects$: Observable<MyObject[]>;

What I want to do is this:
    forkjoin([this.apiService.GetSomeData(), this.myobjects$])
    .pipe(
        map(([mydata, myobjects]) => {
            ...do some stuff
        })
    )
    .subscribe((result) => {
        ...more stuff
   })

The issue is that the 'forkjoin' never completes and calls the map operator.  I'm not sure if the myobjects$ Observable just doesn't complete or what but it just hangs.  I tested this by replacing myobjects$ with of([]) and then the 'forkjoin' completes.
How can I combine my state data with my api data?

I believe you still have to subscribe at the end of the fork join, which may explain why it isn't completing. You can also take both the observables out and let them stand on their own to make sure both are getting data first.

@brent I did but I didn't show it here I'll update it so that it doesn't distract others from what's going on.

okay, it sounds like myobjects$ is the observable not working correctly, can you show some more code from that observable

forkJoin will only emit when all of its sources complete.  Depending on when you want your subscribe logic to execute, you have a few options.
Execute One time only
forkjoin([
  this.apiService.GetSomeData(),
  this.myobjects$.pipe(take(1)), // <--- take(1) 
]).pipe(
  /* ... */
).subscribe(
  result => { /* ... */ }
);

You can use the take operator to cause your observable to complete after one emission, allowing forkJoin to emit the results.
Execute on every source emission
combineLatest([this.apiService.GetSomeData(), this.myobjects$]).pipe(
  /* ... */
).subscribe(
  result => { /* ... */ }
);

If you want to run your subscribe logic every time any source emits, you can use combineLatest.  This doesn't require the sources to complete, it only requires that each source emit at least one value.
Get data then execute whenever myObjects$ emits
this.apiService.GetSomeData().pipe(
  switchMap(mydata => this.myobjects$.pipe(
    map(myobjects => /* ... */
  ))
).subscribe(
  result => { /* ... */ }
);

You can also use switchMap.  The above code takes emissions from your api service call, then maps them to a new observable.  The emissions from this "inner observable" will be emitted.
You can use a nested .pipe() so that your inner logic has access to both the mydata emission as well as the myobjects emissions.
